# combining multiple column values in lines based on identical column

Tags: bash, awk

I need help to improve my working code for combining multiple rows based on identical values for specified columns. 
Here is a sample data:

```
c-i1_pos-at1-v2 162a    AT1G01040.1 2   3422-3443   3433    1
c-i1_pos-at1-v2 162b    AT1G01040.1 2   3422-3443   3433    1
pare-i_226-v2-wt    162a    AT1G01040.1 2   3422-3443   3433    0
pare-i_226-v2-wt    162b    AT1G01040.1 2   3422-3443   3433    0
xrn4-pare-i_ath-227-v2-wt   827 AT1G02860.1 1   258-278 269 1
i2_lib2-v2  156a    AT1G03730.1 4   242-260 252 3
i2_lib2-v2  156b    AT1G03730.1 4   242-260 252 3
i2_lib2-v2  156c    AT1G03730.1 4   242-260 252 3
i2_lib2-v2  156d    AT1G03730.1 4   242-260 252 3
i2_lib2-v2  156e    AT1G03730.1 4   242-260 252 3
```

Basically if values in columns $3,$5 are identical, I want to combine rows for columns $2,$6 (or more), with the unique values of the remaining columns merged like this:

```
AT1G01040.1 3422-3443   3433    162a,162b
AT1G02860.1 258-278 269 827
AT1G03730.1 242-260 252 156a,156b,156c,156d,156e
```

Right now I am trying to do this in multiple steps, based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068314/awk-combining-multiple-lines-conditionally).

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {c=$2 FS $3 FS $5; if (c in a) a[c]=a[c]","$6; else a[c]=$6}END{for (k in a) print k,a[k]}'|awk '{p=$1 FS $2 FS $4; if (p in l) l[p]=l[p]","$3;else l[p]=$3}END{for (m in l) print m,l[m]}' <input.txt
```

Which gives:

```
AT1G01040.1 3422-3443   3433,3433   162a,162b
AT1G02860.1 258-278 269 827
AT1G03730.1 242-260 252 156a,156b,156c,156d,156e
```

I thought I should put the values in the remaining columns as arrays to get my desired output at one step, but I am struggling to figure out the correct context.

Comment: Ideally there should be only one 3433 in row 1, however the code I have up there prints 3433 twice..must be because I messed up something :/

Comment: yes it works perfectly--thanks so much! Now I am going through the code to understand the correct context-- thanks again.

Comment: that will be great :)

Comment: @pasaima I have added an explanation. Hope it is clear now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
awk '{if ( $3 in a ) a[$3] = a[$3]","$2; else a[$3] = $3" "$5" "$6" "$2} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' inputFile
```

Will produce output as

```
AT1G03730.1 242-260 252 156a,156b,156c,156d,156e
AT1G02860.1 258-278 269 827
AT1G01040.1 3422-3443 3433 162a,162b,162a,162b
```

**Explanation**

`a[$3] = $3" "$5" "$6" "$2` creates an array `a` indexed by the third field `$3`, the `else` part ensures that the array is created when the row is encounterd for the first time.

`if ( $3 in a ) a[$3] = a[$3]","$2` if the third field `$3` is already present in the array, append field two `$2` to the array

`END{for (i in a) print a[i]}` `END` block is excecuted at the end of input. Prints the entire array giving the output

**EDIT**

A simpler version would be

```
awk '{( $3 in a ) ? a[$3] = a[$3]","$2 : a[$3] = $3" "$5" "$6" "$2} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' inputFile
```

Thank you Jotne for the suggestion.

Comment: Some golfing of your code: `awk '{a[$3]=($3 in a)?a[$3]","$2:$3FS$5FS$6FS$2} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' file`

Comment: You are welcome.  You could also remove the parentheses, but this will make it harder to read, so best to leave it there.

Comment: @Jotne OP just started using awk, we dont want to make harder for him :)